# How to establish connection with kafka server in Rust

Tags: tcp, apache-kafka, rust

I'm trying to establish connection with kafka server without third party libraries in Rust.
This is the [description](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol) of kafka server TCP protocol

This is my code:

```rust
    fn connect() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
      let stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:9092").expect("Could not connect");

      let mut input_stream = stream.try_clone().unwrap();

      input_stream.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::new(5, 0)));
      input_stream.set_write_timeout(Some(Duration::new(5, 0)));

      /// HERE IS MY PROBLEM. I DON'T KNOW HOW TO ENCODE KAFKA MESSAGE
      let mut data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

      /// api key                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      /// request_api_version      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      /// correlation_id           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(1400);
      buffer.extend_from_slice(&[0; 100]);

      input_stream.write(&mut data)?;
      match input_stream.read(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(b) => {
            println!("read ok - {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer));
        }
        Err(e) => println!("Error {}", e),
      }

      Ok(())
    }

    fn main() {
       connect();
    }
```

How to encode this [kafka message](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_messages) to byte array ?
Variable `data` should be an array of bytes

Comment: Have you looked at this? : https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html

Comment: @SamuelDare No. Thanks, I will take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive code for creating kafka message of next interface

request_api_key => INT16

request_api_version => INT16

correlation_id => INT32

```js
const int16 = (prevBuffer: Buffer, value: number) => {
    const newBuffer = Buffer.alloc(2)
    newBuffer.writeInt16BE(value)
    return Buffer.concat([prevBuffer, newBuffer]);
}

const int32 = (prevBuffer: Buffer, value: number) => {
    const newBuffer = Buffer.alloc(4)
    newBuffer.writeInt32BE(value)
    return Buffer.concat([prevBuffer, newBuffer]);
}

const payload = int31(int16(int16(Buffer.alloc(0), 3), 0),1);
```

The code is shamelessly taken from [kafkajs](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs)